# Ignoring Nested properties in Jackson OnDemand

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am working on a spring boot application with Hibernate as ORM and Jackson as JSON serialiser .

I have three model objects and CRUD operations for all three models.

```
Class Student{
     private Teacher teacher;  // Teacher of the student — to be fetched eagerly
    +Getter/Setter
}

class Teacher {
      private List<Subject> subject;  // List of subjects associated to that user— to be fetched eagerly
      +Getter/Setter 
}

class Subject {
     private long subjectId 
    //Other subject properties
    + Getter/Setter
}
```

Whenever I trigger a get request for student info I get the teacher info which is correct where as I also receive Subject info as well which is unnecessary for me. In the same time when I request for Teacher info, I need Subject info should be associated to that for sure. If I use `@JsonBackReference` for subject I am losing it all the time. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: you might be able to write a custom Jackson filter to conditionally filter out fields that you do not need based upon what is being serialized.

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [JSON Views](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#json-views)

From the spring blog:

```
public class View {
  interface Summary {}
}

public class User {

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private Long id;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private String firstname;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private String lastname;

  private String email;
  private String address;
  private String postalCode;
  private String city;
  private String country;
}

public class Message {

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private Long id;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private LocalDate created;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private String title;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  private User author;

  private List<User> recipients;

  private String body;
}
```

and in the controller

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

  @Autowired
  private MessageService messageService;

  @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
    return messageService.getAll();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  public Message getMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return messageService.get(id);
  }
}
```

PS: No link to http://fasterxml.com/ as it's currently down.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so other know the issue is resolved ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can also annotate like this

```
Class Student{
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("subject")
    private Teacher teacher;  // Teacher of the student — to be fetched eagerly
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you.